# Visibility of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have a list of items (buttons) on one html page and on another html page I have options for different settings such as changing background color, ect. One of the functions I want to add is to be able to hide or show some of the list functions on the first page. Right now a list item is as follows:

```
<li class="ui-state-default">
    <a href="settings.html">
    <img class="image" src="Buttons/Settings.png"/></a>Settings
</li>
```

I know this can probably be done with Javascript but how can I reference each list object? From what I can tell you can't have a `name` field in the `<li>` tag. I tried searching Google but I couldn't reallly find anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `id` or `class` instead of `name`. Are you able to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or prefer pure javascript?

Comment: `ui-state-default` is a jQuery UI class name, isn't it?

Comment: I am using jQuery, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using jQuery UI. Here's how you can select all of the `<li>` in your sample code by `class` and loop through them to perform some action:

```
jQuery('li.ui-state-default').each(function() {
  // do something
});
```

If you want to target a specific `<li>`, you'll need to give it a unique `ID`.
For example:

```
<li class="ui-state-default" id="thisone"></li>

jQuery('li#thisone').show(); // show it
jQuery('li#thisone').hide(); // hide it
```

If you can specify exactly what you're trying to accomplish, I may be able to give a more specific example.

More resources here:
[jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)
[jQuery UI API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/)